# Ways to connect client-side to server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection, client-server

When connecting the client to the server (the server written in node or one of its frameworks) I am told there are 3 ways this can be accomplished.

The first, and most obvious to me, is using `AJAX`.

The second can be done by using `socket.io`.

My question is what is the third?

Does anyone know of a good resource that explains these three ways?

Comment: I think you are getting down votes because your question is fairly broad and your premise is arguably flawed. Do you have a specific problem to solve?

Comment: @RayStantz No, I was simply curious. Thanks for taking the time to at least comment and not just down vote my question. I am sure there are many new developers that will eventually struggle with this question in the future. I see this question as being helpful as a resource for people who are trying to learn.

Comment: Assuming your client is htlm in a browser, you can get a long ways with the html form tag or XMLHttpRequest (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp). I would worry about the other methods when you find a situation where they are lacking. I tend to learn better when things are in context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of this method:

Message Passing, Shared memory, RPC and java RMI.

To know more about [Process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

[Details about client and server Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model#Client_and_server_communication) follow these links

Answer (score -1):

Just to answer your broad question:

[DDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Data_Protocol), as being used by [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)